# Pip Install Keras and TensorFlow missing packages?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pip

I used pip to install keras and tensorflow, yet when I import subpackages from keras, my shell fails a check for PyBfloat16_Type.tp_base.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling tensorflow, but I don't know for certain what is causing this error.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
```

```
3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)]
Python Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>[evaluate machineLearning.py]
Using TensorFlow backend. 2019-04-21 00:31:22.995541: F tensorflow/python/lib/core/bfloat16.cc:675] Check failed: PyBfloat16_Type.tp_base != nullptr 
aborted (disconnected)
>>>
```

Can someone help me solve this issue?

Comment: can you add your tensorflow and keras versions here?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have a few options to try:

First, try to uninstall and re-install the TensorFlow and see whether the problem is resolved or not (replace `tensorflow` with `tensorflow-gpu` in the following commands if you have installed the GPU version):

```
pip uninstall tensorflow 

pip install --no-cache-dir tensorflow
```

If the problem is not resolved, try to do the same thing with `numpy`:

```
pip uninstall numpy

pip install --no-cache-dir numpy
```

Hopefully, one of these two would resolve the problem.

Comment: This solved the problem! Uninstalling/reinstalling numpy did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to downgrade python to 3.6 (I know some people have troubles with tensorflow and keras using python 3.7). One simple way is to download anaconda, create a new environment with python 3.6, then install tensorflow and keras.

`conda create -n myenv python=3.6`

`conda activate myenv`

`pip3 install tensorflow`

`pip3 install keras`